# cross-reference to figure in R Markdown with html output is not working

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, figure, caption

I would like to show a nice cross-reference to a picture in the HTML document I'm creating with R Markdown. However, even if I followed [the bookdown section on cross-references](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html), I cannot get the reference to show in the final HTML output. I'm working in R Studio, if that helps. .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "ppp"
author: "ppp"
date: "July 4, 2017"
output: 
  html_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r foo, fig.cap="$f_{p}$ as a function of $g$ for various values of $r=\\frac{\\rho_{w}}{\\rho_{a}}$"}
# All defaults
include_graphics("download.jpg")
```

A cross-reference to figure \@ref(fig:foo).
````

The output I get is

[image]

So the caption is rendering correctly, but the cross-reference is not being created. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. But are you using `bookdown`? If you follow https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/get-started.html, and use bookdown project as in https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-minimal. Then you should get the result you want.

For example, I use https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-minimal and modify the `index.Rmd` to something like this, and the cross reference shows correctly.

````
---
title: "A Book"
author: "Frida Gomam"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::gitbook: default
  bookdown::pdf_book: default
---


```{r foo, fig.cap="$f_{p}$ as a function of $g$ for various values of $r=\\frac{\\rho_{w}}{\\rho_{a}}$", echo=FALSE}
# All defaults
knitr::include_graphics("download.png")
```

A cross-reference to figure \@ref(fig:foo).
````

**Update:** Modify the output field to `bookdown::html_document2` seems to generate the html document similar to `rmarkdown::html_document`.

Comment: I hadn't understood that `bookdown` was a different package from `rmarkdown`: thanks for the clarification. Isn't it possible to get cross-references in plain `rmarkdown`? If not, I could accept your answer, **if** you modify it so that the file renders to an HTML file, instead than to an HTML file.

Comment: `bookdown::html_document2` seems to be similar to `rmarkdown::html_document`.