# Rmarkdown with html, how to reference figures?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Using RMarkdown I always generate pdf documents via Rmd -> pandoc -> TeX -> pdflatex -> pdf and accomplish figure references using `\\label{something}` in the `fig.cap` as in the follow example:

````
---
title: "Foo"
author: "Mark Andrews"
date: "10 January 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

See Figure \ref{figfoo} and see Figure \ref{figbar}. 

```{r fig1, fig.cap='A figure\\label{figfoo}'}
plot(rnorm(10))
```


```{r fig2, fig.cap='Another figure\\label{figbar}'}
plot(rnorm(10))
```
````

If I change `output: pdf_document` to `output: html_document`, that does not work, understandably because it is relying on LaTeX's cross referencing system.

So how do Figure references work with `html_document` in RMarkdown?

The following does not work:

````
---
title: "Foo"
author: "Mark Andrews"
date: "10 January 2019"
output: html_document
---

See Figure \@ref(fig:fig1) and see Figure \@ref(fig:fig2). 

```{r fig1, fig.cap='A figure}'}
plot(rnorm(10))
```


```{r fig2, fig.cap='Another figure'}
plot(rnorm(10))
```
````

But the following does work:

````
---
title: "Foo"
author: "Mark Andrews"
date: "10 January 2019"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

See Figure \@ref(fig:fig1) and see Figure \@ref(fig:fig2). 

```{r fig1, fig.cap='A figure}'}
plot(rnorm(10))
```


```{r fig2, fig.cap='Another figure'}
plot(rnorm(10))
```
````

Does that mean that the only way to cross-reference figures when producing html from Rmarkdown is to use `output: bookdown::html_document2`. That's fine, if so, but am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cross-reference to figure in R Markdown with html output is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018180/cross-reference-to-figure-in-r-markdown-with-html-output-is-not-working)

Comment: The answer is yes. That is the only portable way that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having heard from Yihui Xie, I think we can take it for granted that yes, the only way to do figure cross references in html_document in rmarkdown is to do

```
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---
```

in the header.